# Azure Resource Manager (ARM) Import Databases (Bacpac) Error (Closed)

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-resource-manager

I am using ARM template to perform **Import Azure SQL databases** from **bacpac** files storing on my storage account.

However I am getting unexpected Bad Request error from Azure.
The same ARM template has been working fine just a few weeks ago.

When I try to do the Import Databases in the new Azure portal manually, I am also getting error from Azure, but they didn't specify the error detail.

I have tried for three different locations: Southeast Asia, North Europe and Central US but all have failed.

Below is my ARM template portion for database server and database import.

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
  "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
    "properties": {
        "administratorLogin": "[parameters('dbLogin')]",
        "administratorLoginPassword": "[parameters('dbPassword')]",
        "version": "12.0"
    },
  "name": "[parameters('sqlServerName')]",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "firewallrules",
      "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
        "properties": {
            "endIpAddress": "0.0.0.0",
            "startIpAddress": "0.0.0.0"
        },
      "name": "AllowAllWindowsAzureIps",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('sqlServerName'))]"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "databases",
      "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
      "properties": {
        "edition": "[parameters('databaseEdition')]",
        "collation": "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS",
        "maxSizeBytes": "[parameters('maxDatabaseSize')]",
        "requestedServiceObjectiveId": "[parameters('dbServiceObjectiveLevel')]"
      },
      "name": "[parameters('webDatabaseName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('sqlServerName'))]"
      ],
      "resources": [
        {
          "type": "extensions",
          "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
          "properties": {
            "operationMode": "Import",
            "storageKey": "[parameters('bacpacStorageKey')]",
            "storageKeyType": "Primary",
            "administratorLogin": "[parameters('dbLogin')]",
            "administratorLoginPassword": "[parameters('dbPassword')]",
            "storageUri": "[parameters('webBacpacUrl')]"
          },
          "name": "Import",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases', parameters('sqlServerName'), parameters('webDatabaseName'))]"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "databases",
      "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
      "properties": {
        "edition": "[parameters('databaseEdition')]",
        "collation": "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS",
        "maxSizeBytes": "[parameters('maxDatabaseSize')]",
        "requestedServiceObjectiveId": "[parameters('dbServiceObjectiveLevel')]"
      },
      "name": "[parameters('coreDatbaseName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('sqlServerName'))]"
      ],
      "resources": [
        {
          "type": "extensions",
          "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
          "properties": {
            "operationMode": "Import",
            "storageKey": "[parameters('bacpacStorageKey')]",
            "storageKeyType": "Primary",
            "administratorLogin": "[parameters('dbLogin')]",
            "administratorLoginPassword": "[parameters('dbPassword')]",
            "storageUri": "[parameters('coreBacpacUrl')]"
          },
          "name": "Import",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases', parameters('sqlServerName'), parameters('coreDatbaseName'))]"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "databases",
      "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
      "properties": {
        "edition": "[parameters('databaseEdition')]",
        "collation": "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS",
        "maxSizeBytes": "[parameters('maxDatabaseSize')]",
        "requestedServiceObjectiveId": "[parameters('dbServiceObjectiveLevel')]"
      },
      "name": "[parameters('mastrerDatabaseName')]",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', parameters('sqlServerName'))]"
      ],
      "resources": [
        {
          "type": "extensions",
          "apiVersion": "2014-04-01-preview",
          "properties": {
            "operationMode": "Import",
            "storageKey": "[parameters('bacpacStorageKey')]",
            "storageKeyType": "Primary",
            "administratorLogin": "[parameters('dbLogin')]",
            "administratorLoginPassword": "[parameters('dbPassword')]",
            "storageUri": "[parameters('masterBacpacUrl')]"
          },
          "name": "Import",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases', parameters('sqlServerName'), parameters('mastrerDatabaseName'))]"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The error from Azure portal for my ARM deployment:
[image]

Any help or advice is appreciated!

Note: I have suspected this could be due to platform issue but there is no issue reported for the past few days on the locations I tried based on the 
[Azure status history](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/#history)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verified with Microsoft Azure Support and they confirmed this is a platform issue.

Update:
The issue is verified resolved after Microsoft resolved the platform issue related to Import Database.